# What does "Do you" mean as an answer?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I saw this on twitter and I'd like to know what he meant with that, because it seems that "Do you" is a question but he is using it as an answer.

Question:

> Is it ok if I spent $55 on pokecoins?

Answer:

> Do you, bruh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Urban Dictionary

> [do you](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=do%20you)
>
> - Do what you feel is best for you, in short, do you.
> - 1. acting in a way that satisfies you, not caring at all about what others think nor about your actions and/or consequences
>   2. following your heart

I suppose it's slang (I don't know the right terminology). In this instance, *do you* basically means something like *do whatever you like* or *do what your heart desires*. In other words, the respondent is suggesting that the inquirer go for it.

Comment: @William: It doesn't make sense to me. If I were you I wouldn't make any attempt to learn and repeat this usage, since almost no native speakers would understand what you meant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it was a north american guy who answered like this, he lives in California, maybe it's regional.

Comment: @William: More likely localized to some small group(s) of people using Internet online text "chat" facilities.

Comment: @William I think it's more of a younger crowd thing. It's been around for a while, at least in the US. [Do You Boo Boo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L9AShaXoxs).

Comment: @Max Yeah, the guy who answered is like 23